# Revert values back when changing tabs in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I use jQueryUI's tabs and when a user changes a form in the tab, it promprts the user that a change has been made.

My question is, how do I revert the values before being changed when the user presses 'OK' on my confirm() prompt?

Comment: you will need to be more specific, and posting some code may help. Do you just want to reset your form when some button is clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to keep track of what the values were before changing them... so something like this should work for you:

```
var oldValues = {};
$(function() {
    $(":input").each(function() {
        oldValues[$(this).attr("id")] = $(this).val();
    });
});
function revertValues() {
    for (var oldVal in oldValues) {
        $("#" + oldVal).val(oldValues[oldVal]);
    }
}
```

And then just call `revertValues` when you hit OK in your confirmation dialog.

A few notes:

- I just wrote this code straight into the browser, so it's completely untested...
- Assuming you have other inputs on other tabs, you'll need to change the `:input` selector and keep different sets of `oldValues` for each tab (& then obviously only revert the values for the current tab.